# Running Android NavigationDrawer example on older android devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation

I've downloaded [NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) example and tested it on my device with android JB and it worked great. I changed the app to use support library and ported it to android api level 8 (Froyo):

Extending Activity from `ActionBarActivity`
imports are as below

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

All calls to `getActionBar()` changed to `getSupportActionBar()`
All calls to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` changed to `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`
All calls to `getFragmentManager()` changed to `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Code built with no error and installed on the Froyo device with no error but after running it I got force close. I debugged app and everything seems OK. After reaching end of onCreate() method, app crashes. I looked up into the log and find out that there is no error related to this app. Take a look:

```
11-14 01:25:10.589: D/dalvikvm(19350): Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-14 01:25:10.877: E/Trace(19350): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-14 01:25:11.241: D/dalvikvm(19350): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 123K, 2% free 8723K/8896K, paused 21ms, total 46ms
11-14 01:25:11.249: I/dalvikvm-heap(19350): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.938MB for 1440012-byte allocation
11-14 01:25:11.257: D/dalvikvm(19350): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 2% free 10126K/10304K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
11-14 01:25:11.261: D/dalvikvm(19350): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 10126K/10304K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 4ms
11-14 01:25:11.277: D/dalvikvm(19350): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 10126K/10304K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
11-14 01:25:11.297: I/dalvikvm-heap(19350): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.428MB for 5760012-byte allocation
11-14 01:25:11.309: D/dalvikvm(19350): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 15751K/15932K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
11-14 01:25:11.309: D/dalvikvm(19350): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 15751K/15932K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 5ms
11-14 01:25:11.397: D/libEGL(19350): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
11-14 01:25:11.405: D/(19350): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8332948, tid 19350
11-14 01:25:12.565: D/libEGL(19350): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
11-14 01:25:12.565: D/libEGL(19350): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
11-14 01:25:14.273: W/EGL_emulation(19350): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-14 01:25:14.345: D/OpenGLRenderer(19350): Enabling debug mode 0
11-14 01:25:14.397: I/Choreographer(19350): Skipped 181 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-14 01:25:41.881: W/EGL_emulation(19350): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-14 01:25:46.341: W/EGL_emulation(19350): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-14 01:36:48.953: D/dalvikvm(19350): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

I have no Idea what is wrong here. Any help appreciated!

EDIT: MainActivity code

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This example illustrates a common usage of the DrawerLayout widget
 * in the Android support library.
 * <p/>
 * <p>When a navigation (left) drawer is present, the host activity should detect presses of
 * the action bar's Up affordance as a signal to open and close the navigation drawer. The
 * ActionBarDrawerToggle facilitates this behavior.
 * Items within the drawer should fall into one of two categories:</p>
 * <p/>
 * <ul>
 * <li><strong>View switches</strong>. A view switch follows the same basic policies as
 * list or tab navigation in that a view switch does not create navigation history.
 * This pattern should only be used at the root activity of a task, leaving some form
 * of Up navigation active for activities further down the navigation hierarchy.</li>
 * <li><strong>Selective Up</strong>. The drawer allows the user to choose an alternate
 * parent for Up navigation. This allows a user to jump across an app's navigation
 * hierarchy at will. The application should treat this as it treats Up navigation from
 * a different task, replacing the current task stack using TaskStackBuilder or similar.
 * This is the only form of navigation drawer that should be used outside of the root
 * activity of a task.</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * <p>Right side drawers should be used for actions, not navigation. This follows the pattern
 * established by the Action Bar that navigation should be to the left and actions to the right.
 * An action should be an operation performed on the current contents of the window,
 * for example enabling or disabling a data overlay on top of the current content.</p>
 */
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see any caused by part in logcat also post the relevant code

Comment: No. There is no any Exception related to the code and as I said onCreate() reaches end with no error.

Comment: its a crash may be due to some excpetion and it must be the code that caused it. cross check the logcat. Post the relevant code

Comment: I changed nothing in google's code except the ones I told in the question. just changing calls to support library related calls.

Comment: I run app on newer android devices with no error.

Comment: without the code its hard to tell what would have happenned

Comment: i guess there is no enough heap space that's the reason it's crashing

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad runs fine on 4.0 checking on api 8

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad what is theme that you used?

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad it does crash on api level 8 an i do get an exception. So i guess you need to run your code again check the logcat and post the same here. I could run the same code on api level 8 with few changes. However you case may be differrent

Comment: @Raghunandan I thought that it was a memory problem so I down sample all the images in drawable folder but the error is still there. I removed Theme tag in manifest and changed nothing in `android-support-v7-appcompat` librarry project. Would you please send me your code so I can compare these two codes? My email address is ali.behzadian at gmail dot com. Thank you.

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad i can answer and hopefully solve the problem if you specify the type of problem you are facing if its a memory problem won't you get `OutOfMemoryException` ? use  `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"`

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad i will post the changes see if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector" // used a selector you can remove this
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
  />
```

Removed

```
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
 android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
```

I also used

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
     android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

and

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

In manifest

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

activty_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Snap on the emulator

I changed the background of list items. However you can keep that default

[image]

Comment: Removing those two attributes in `drawer_list_item.xml` with `?android...` solved the problem. Thank you man!